# Issue with adding KeyPress event to main panel in form

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, keypress

I have a problem with adding eventhandler to panel.

I have already checked answers here in stack, however they are not working for me.

```
Panel panel_glowny = new Panel();
panel_glowny.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(object sender,KeyEventArgs e)
```

Visual Studio tells me that `sender` does not exist.

Comment: Did you see, read, understand my post?

Comment: @TaW yes I saw your post, this night I will check it and give you reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem goes beyond the wrong syntax and chosing the wrong, unsupported event..:

A `Panel` does not receive keypresses or even focus. Which is why the `KeyPress` handler is not supported in `Intellisense`. You can add it but it won't work.

So you need the help of the form **and** need to set the focus to the panel in code..

We need to set the Form's `KeyPreview` property so it catches all keypresses; and you also need to set the focus to the Panel **every time** you want it to receive those keypresses. Make sure not to move the Focus away again..!

```
panel_glowny.PreviewKeyDown += panel_glowny_PreviewKeyDown;  // necessary once
KeyPreview = true;                                        // necessary once
panel_glowny.Focus();                                  // may be necessary more than once!!

void panel_glowny_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: Everything is working correct! thank You very much for help :)
i have also found very interesting description of problem that you provided me with. this is very helpfull and I hope that it will prevent me from doing more such errors :)

Answer (score 0):

The keypress event handler needs to be a method that accepts those parameters
For an inline version like you have something like this

```
Panel panel_glowny = new Panel();
panel_glowny.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler((sender, e) => { ... })
```

you can also remove the new KeyPressEventHandler statement and shorten it to something like this

```
Panel panel_glowny = new Panel();
panel_glowny.KeyPress += (sender, e) => { ... };
```